# AWS s3 file upload in express js: whats the difference between upload vs multipart upload

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to AWS s3 using express js,instead of `putObject` i am using `upload` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property function

```
       var options ={
            partSize: 5242880, queueSize: 1
        };
        console.time('Uploadtime');
        s3.upload(params,options,function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     {
                console.timeEnd('Uploadtime');
                console.log("uploaded",data);
                res.json({
                    'status':'Uploaded'
                });
            }           // successful response
        });
```

I think upload and multipart upload do the same thing(am i correct??)
My question is do i need to use multi part upload or stay with `upload` method.

From the docs i can't get the similarities between upload and multipartupload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

upload and multipart upload perform the same action but there are the few advantage of multipart upload

1. You can upload parts in parallel to improve throughput.
2. Smaller part size minimizes the impact of restarting a failed upload
   due to a network error.
3. You can upload object parts over time. Once you initiate a multipart
   upload
4. there is no expiry; you must explicitly complete or abort the
   multipart upload.
5. You can upload an object as you are creating it.

So you can decide which one you should go with according to your need , multipart is recommended when the object you are uploading is big in size .

Comment: Usallay image size up to 50mb so which one is sutiable??

Comment: @Jabaa depending on the bandwidth. However, for 50 mb files, I'd go with multipart uploads

Comment: @hjpotter i think multipart upload is sutiable for my needs, is there any simple tutorial for that,tried so many but most of them are confusing

Comment: I just tried this package but it didn't worked , no errors is shown but the file is not uploaded